# How does IEEE 754 define equal?

Tags: equals, equality, ieee-754

**How does IEEE-754 define equal for "regular" double floating point numbers?
Is the java implementation of Double.equal in accordance with IEEE-754?**

If I leave out the special values like NaN, -0, etc. are IEEE-754 double floating numbers equal, if and only if they have the same 64bits representing them?

IEEE-754 defines how an approximation of "10.12" is to be represented in 64bits as double. IEEE-754 defines how to calculate "6.0+4.12", by representing both values in 64bits and how to derive 64bits that represent the result. I know that the two 64bit patterns I receive are not the same.

What I do not know, if IEEE-754 defines some special equal-relation for those 64bit patterns that still defines them as equal?

I see a lot of documents on how to resemble mathematical equal with floating point numbers. They all claim that 10.12 != 6.0+4.12  if represented and calculated according to IEEE-754. If I do that in java with Double objects, java also claims that the two values are not equal. I like to know if the equal operation of java Double is in accordance with IEEE-754.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I leave out the special values like NaN, -0, etc. are IEEE-754 double floating number equal, if and only if they have the same 64bits representing them?

Yes.

> I like to know if the equal operation of java Double is in accordance with IEEE-754.

No, there are two exceptions [specifically listed in `Double.equals` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

1. Two `Double` objects corresponding to `NaN` are equal;
2. `Double` objects corresponding to zero and to negative zero aren't equal.

Equality on primitive `double` *is* according to IEEE-754.

Comment: Thank you for the clear "Yes". Thank you also for the statement about primitive `double`. Having my assumption confirmed, made the `Double.equals` documentation a valueble read.